# How to install email client on emulator

Tags: android, email, android-emulator, installation

I have to build an email sending sending program and now i want to test it. but emulator is saying that "Their is no app to perform this action".

So how can i install gmail or some other email client on the emulator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the Email app, and configure an account with it. Then you will be able to send email intents.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use gmail account on default email app on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your Emulator with "Google API" rather than just choose "Android"

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "Allow less secure apps: ON" in Sign-in & security settings in your gmail account before you use gmail account for Standard Email client in Android Emulator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using normal Gmail account from browser or Gmail app, from settings enable "install insecure applications" and the go to tab "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" and set "IMAP access enabled" then on theAVD use an IMAP account on the virtual device with your usual login and password but don't forget that when that fails to set the server to m.google.com.  Worked for me.