# android sdk - how to get native mail client in virtual device?

Tags: android, email, testing, sdk

I just downloaded the Android SDK package and went through the process of creating and launching a virtual Android device (4.2.2). Now I am trying to find the native email client. There doesn't seem to be one installed, and if I try to use Contacts to "Sign into an account", the button clicks, but nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I install or access the native Android email client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an older version for the AVD (i.e., 4.0.3), that will have the native email client (with exchange support).  For whatever reason, the native email/exchange client does not seem to be included in the 4.2 emulator images.

Answer (score 0):

**For lower versions of Android:**

You need to modify some core components of an *Emulator Image*. Follow [these instructions](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/01/android-market-on-emulator-22.html) on setting up the *Android Market* on an Emulator. This will also add email functionality. Also keep in mind that the `IMG`s this solution provides could potentially be phishing for your email account and password, so I recommend creating a new *gmail* account to use just for testing the hacked emulator.

**For higher versions of Android:**

It sounds like you aren't able to do this easy solution:
[How to install email client on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107457/how-to-install-email-client-on-emulator)

so I'd recommend you check out some other posts on adding the Google Play store, such as [Google Play on Android 4.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator)